# Could not find or load main class gain.Gui

Tags: java, user-interface, ant

Ok,

So I am having an issue with my jar file. I compiled in fedora and ran in windows 7 however I am receiving the error "Error: Could not find or load main class gain.Gui" I looked in the jar file and the class Gui exists in the gain folder. my meta info file is :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.1
Created-By: 1.7.0_45-mockbuild_2013_10_16_17_47-b00 (Oracle Corporatio
 n)
Class-Path: C:/temp/mysql.jar lib/AbsoluteLayout
 .jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: gain.Gui
```

Is there anyway to force the JVM to give me more error information? If there is any more information required for this issue please just ask. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: `C:/temp/mysql.jar` looks worrisome.  Start by trying to run the application from the command line using something like `java -jar yourJar.jar`

Comment: Are you sure the file `gain/Gui.class` exists?

Comment: @MadProgrammer- I know that is improper but that is how I am implementing the JBDC Driver, and also that is how I am starting the program. yes and yes

Comment: For the record I found my issue it was an sql table issue, had absolutely nothing to do with the JVM thank you all for the help!